# How to get smooth triangle shape when subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Is there any method getting a smooth triangle shape when subdivision modifier is applied to a mesh? (Without using Boolean modifier).

[image]

Comment: Hello. But why starting from a grid if you want a triangle? Or do you want a "stepped" triangle?

Comment: By the way, you most likely have inverted normals here.

Comment: I'm trying to learn the topology method if there is one, or a trick, to getting a triangle shape on a sub divided surface.

https://ibb.co/60bNd6j

Comment: if there's no reason to subdivide (like in your reference image), don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start from a circle with 3 vertices (i.e equilateral triangle) + a plane (1).

Subdivide like in (2).

Bevel the vertex corners <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (3).

Delete the left part and add a mirror and a subdivision (4).

Join the faces for the outer part (5).

Joint de faces for the inner part (6).

[image]

Extrude down the center faces and add support edges to the extrusion (7).

[image]

[image]